# Returning to my app after changing a contact with an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Here is my code to open a contact edit view:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
i.setData(contactUri);
startActivityForResult(i, INTENT_EDIT_CONTACT);
```

After performing some changes and saving my contact I always get a second view showing me all contact details again in a read only mode (I would like to return directly to my app if possible!)
To return to my app from here I have to select my "go back" system button. This results in returning back into my app but with RESULT_CANCELED instead of RESULT_OK in my onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) method.

How can I return directly back to my app after updating a contact or at least avoid a RESULT_CANCELED result code.

BTW: I do not want to provide my own dialog for updating contact details, my goal is to use the provided dialog from android contacts app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following line solved this problem for me

```
i.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
```

Even thou the documentation seems to be related to another issue, this line fixed my problems on my Android 4.1.2 device:
http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html

Answer (score 1):

*

```
Intent intenti = new Intent(your context(or service), your class.class);
            intenti.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            startActivity(intenti);
```

*